# Does this vector bundle have a natural description?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Work over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider a smooth divisor of bidegree $(2,1)$ in $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$, for example $$X = \{\sum_{i=1}^{2} x_{i} y_{i}^2 = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2.$$

Then, if I am not mistaken, the projection to the $\mathbb{P}^2$ with coordinates $[y_0:y_1:y_2]$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle in the strong sense, i.e. all fibres are isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Hence, we may write $X = \mathbb{P}(E)$ where $E$ is a rank $2$ vector bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ (since the Brauer group of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ vanishes). I did some calculations in the cohomology ring of $X$ which suggest that we can take $E$ with $c_{1}(E) = 2H$, $c_{2}(E) = 4H^2$, where $H$ in hyperplance class. In particular $E$ doesn't split. Although note that $E$ is only defined up to taking a tensor product with a line bundle.

**Question:** Is there a "natural description" of $E$?

More precisely I am asking if some representative up to the equivelance relation of tensoring with a line bundle has a natural description.

I am hoping for something analogous to the fact that a divisor $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$ with bidegree $(1,1)$ satsifies $Y \cong \mathbb{P}(T\mathbb{P}^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description depends on the convention used for the projectivization. If $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is defined as the scheme parameterizing lines in fibers of $E$, then the bundle $E$ is defined by the exact sequence
$$
0 \to E \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus 3} \stackrel{(y_0^2,y_1^2,y_2^2)}\to \mathcal{O}(2) \to 0.
$$
And if the opposite convention is used, you should replace the above bundle by its dual.